# Angular 4 Form Invalid Does Not Prevent Enter From Submitting The Form

Tags: angular, validation

I have a simple form with several fields, a Cancel button and a Submit button. I am using Angular Material within the form for the controls. I have developed a custom validation directive which makes the form invalid if certain conditions are met. The validation makes the Submit button disable, as expected, but the Enter button on the keyboard is not disabled when the form is invalid.

I don't want the Enter button always disabled, only when the form is invalid. Can this be achieved?

My form is declared as follows:

```
<form class="dialog-form"
          novalidate
          #areaForm="ngForm"
          (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

My buttons are as follows:

```
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-button
            [mat-dialog-close]="true"
            (click)="onCancel()">
        Cancel
    </button>

    <button mat-button
            [mat-dialog-close]="true"
            color="primary"
            type="button"
            (click)="onSubmit()"
            [disabled]="areaForm.form.invalid">
        {{data.buttonText}}
    </button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Any guidance would be welcome. Thanks.

Edit
Creating an `@Input` reference to the `FormGroup` appears to allow me to check if the form is valid before closing the `mat-dialog` and submitting the form:

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {

        // Close the dialog.
        this.dialogRef.close(this.areaForCreation);
    };
};
```

Comment: Where is your directive ? On the form ? On the input fields ?

Comment: Good question. I have the same problem with custom directives on the form or directly on the input field. Even with a built-in validation such as `required` with `minlength="4"` on an input field I have the following problem: The user can click in the field, delete the text back to less than 4 characters (at which point the Submit button visually disables) then press Enter and the form is submitted. If however the user clicks in the field, deletes back to less than 4 characters and clicks out of the field, or press Tab, then Enter does not Submit.

Comment: :D no, I mean, you said you created a directive. Where are you actually putting it ? This will shape my answer to you, so I would rather not miss the point of your question !

Comment: Some forms have a validation directive applied at `Form` level, if they need to determine the form's validity using several fields. Some forms have a directive applied at `Input` level if I only need to determine the validity of the value entered in the field. It appears the problem though is not related to any validator, but to the Enter key submitting the form even if the form is `invalid`.

Comment: Again, I don't care about that, I want to know what you used. If you're looking for a solution, I can give you a very easy one, but the way you wrote that, you are actually facing an issue, do I need to know what you did to lead you the right way.

Answer (score 3):

It should be `areaForm.invalid` not `areaForm.form.invalid`